# Three containers first contain $r$ red balls second $g$ green balls and third contains $b$ blue balls

Tags: probability, combinations

Three containers first contain $r$ red balls second $g$ green balls and third contains $b$ blue balls ..at all I want to draw 3 balls and it doesn't matter from which container .. the problem is to calculate the number of combinations of drawn balls with putting in mind the following :

(R,R,G) is the same as (G,R,R) and so on. Secondly there shouldn't be three elements of the same color.. in other words sets like (R,R,R) or (G,G,G) must not be counted.

Comment: I don't know where to start

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question.  Does $(r, b, g)$ mean that you have placed a red ball in the first container, a blue ball in the second container, and a green ball in the third container?  Are you interested in the number of ways of distributing three balls selected from the $r$ red balls, $g$ green balls, and $b$ blue balls to the three containers so that you never distribute three balls of the same color?  Please clarify your question.

Comment: I want to calculate the number of combinations formed by drawing 3 balls from these containers so that the three balls are not of the same color .. they can be two red and one blue .. one red , one blue and one green and so on what is the number of those sets ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like classic stars and bars.  You can place two bars at any underscore (two bars at the same underscore is valid) to determine the combination of red, green and blue balls.  The stars represent the possible color of balls.

$$\_*\_*\_*\_$$

Lets say everything to the left of the first bar is red, everything between the two bars is green and everything to the right of the second bar is blue.  Then one possible combination would be:

$$\_\,R|G|B\,\_$$

Representing one of each color.  Or this arrangement to represent choosing two red and one blue:

$$\_\,R\,\_\,R||B\,\_$$

Then to determine the total number of possible combinations you must realize that there are 4 places to place the first bar and 4 places to place the second bar and $2!$ ways that the bars can be placed (first bar then second or second bar then first) so the total number of ways to place both bars ignoring the order they are placed in is $\frac{4^{2}}{2!}=8$

But there are three placements that are not allowed:

$$\_\,R\,\_\,R\,\_\,R||$$
$$|G\,\_\,G\,\_\,G|$$
$$||B\,\_\,B\,\_\,B\,\_$$

So there are $8-3=5$ possible combinations.